# Why can't footer view be removed/added back into ListView without losing onClickListener?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have re-written this question for clarity:

I have a ListView, and a FooterView with a refresh Button inside the Footer.

I keep references to all of them at Activity level

```
  ListView myListView;
  View     footerView;
  Button   refreshBtn;
```

In

```
 onCreate(Bundle)
 {
          footerView = inflate footer view etc;
          refreshBtn = footerView.findViewById(R.id.refresh_btn);
          refreshBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
          myListView.addFooter(footerView);
 }

  onClick()
 {
     // refresh clicked.  Don't show FooterView anymore unless its needed again
      myListView.removeView(footerView)  //

 }

 onRefresthResult()
 {
    // looks like we need to try refresh again.  So lets add the refresh footer back in.
    // THIS DOES NOT WORK. CLICKING refreshBtn does NOTHING.
     myListView.addFooter(footerView);
     resetListAdapter();


     // Now refresh button does NOTHING. unless we do THIS below instead.

     // THIS DOES WORK, BUT WHY?
     footerView = inflate footer view.   (Why does this need to be done again. footerView was not null both it and the refreshBtn seemed to have valid values).
     refreshBtn = footerView.findViewById(R.id.refresh_btn);
     refreshBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

     // Note footerView reference was always valid and resetting onClick 
        without reinflating did not work.

 }
```

My only theory is that somehow when you remove a view it gets marked in some way,  and so a new instance of the footer view must be added back in?

Comment: do you mean by remove it change the view visibility ?

Comment: every time in your adapter `getView` you must set the `ClickListener` again, if your trying to make something like `Pull to Refresh` you can find open source projects like this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hey You can make your footer invisible in onclick function like**

```
footerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```